# firebase login --no-localhost failed

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

Every time I run:

```
firebase login --no-localhost.
```

It will show:

> Error: Unable to authenticate using the provided code. Please try again.

[image: Error: Unable to authenticate using the provided code. Please try again.]

I tried over 20 times, But it didn't work, I wish any one can help me. Thanks!